# ServerSocket code works on PC, doesn't work on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have the following ServerSocket code which accepts incoming clients:

```
public class Network {

private Socket              socket = null;
private ServerSocket        serverSocket = null;
private OutputStream        outputStream = null;
private BufferedReader      reader = null;
private PrintWriter         writer = null;
private boolean             firstConnect = true;
private String              packet;
private static Thread       serverThread = null;

public Network() {
    serverThread = new Thread(ServerThread());
    serverThread.start();
}

private Runnable ServerThread() {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1440);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Listening for packets....");
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
                System.out.println("User connected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
}


class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(read);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on PC. However when running on an android device, it never accepts clients.

I have already taken a look at the following potential problems:

- Minimum port on linux is 1024. I am using port 1440;
- Port 1440 is not in use. Server works fine on PC, just not on android;
- The problem is not my specific device or android OS. I have used a Galaxy S4, Galaxy S6 and Sony Z3 compact, all on different OS versions starting from Android 4.3;
- I have added "android.permission.INTERNET" in the AndroidManifest;

Why would the code still not be working on my android devices?

Comment: With what kind of client are you trying to connect? From where? How does the clienr react? Server code looks ok. So show client code and tell your setup.

Comment: @Pouthrathor I got the base code from here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/ and some other sources, implying the code should be working fine on android.

Comment: @greenapps If my client was the problem then why would I be able to connect to the server if that server is run on desktop instead of android? But if you still think it might be the problem I can update my post with the code.

Comment: Show the used ip. Server and client in same WLAN?

Comment: @greenapps I used my public IP gotten from sites like "whatismyip.org" (82.217.110.xxx).

Comment: Yes,  both android devices use the same wifi connection

Comment: Impossible to use a public ip. Public ip of the android device where your server is running on? Impossible. Your mobile provider will not allow that. So you are not using wifi.

Comment: Wifi connection? Then the client should use the WLAN ip of the server device. The loca iip.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused with the term "public IP", either way I am using the IP that displays when I navigate to "whatismyip.org" with one of my devices connected to wifi.

Comment: @greenapps Can you tell me what that local IP is in other words?

Comment: Didnt you post this problem already before? I answered the same.

Comment: Do not use whatismyip.org. Just go to wifi settings in your android device. Properties of the wifi connection.

Comment: Whatismyip.org tells you the ip of the router. All your pcs and android devices have that same external ip.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am now using another IP and getting an error that the connection is refused, which actually makes me happy, because I finally have an error I can look in! I am guessing I have to port-forward that exact IP in my router's settings?

Comment: With another IP I mean I am now using the IP of my wifi connection.

Comment: Be more specific and tell both the ip of the server device and the client device. And then tell which ip the client uses. No you do not need to forward ports if you are in the same LAN. The problem is that you should better tell what you are doing.

Comment: `I am now using the IP of my wifi connection` ???? Much to vague. Nobody knows what you are doing. Wifi connection? Of what? Come to the point as i asked before.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that I am not used to talking about networking in the english language. If I understand correctly, you want me to tell the IP of my wifi, which I can find in the advanced settings of the wifi I am connected to. It is as follows: 192.168.178.18

Comment: Read again what i asked. Not an ip of your wifi. Because what would that be your wifi? I asked for the two ip adresses of your two android devices.

Comment: Alright, the two IP-addresses of the devices are as follows: Galaxy S6 - 192.168.178.18; Sony Z3 compact: 192.168.178.47.

Comment: My god. And which is the server device? And which is the client device?

Comment: I'm sorry. The server device is the galaxy S6 and the client device is the Z3 compact.

Comment: Im not interested in makes. So server is the .18 and the client is the .47. He he. And now the last one: which ip is used by the client to connect to the server?

Comment: I was using the IP I get when browsing to "whatismyip.org" on my computer. You are probably going to tell me this is the wrong IP.

Comment: I already told you twice that that was the wrong ip. Now why would i ask for the lan ip of your server?

Comment: My god that is wrong. Use another ip. Why would i have asked for the lan/wifi ip of your server device? Think!

Comment: I thought you meant which IP I had filled in the code - which is the IP I get when going to that website. Do you mean another IP?

Comment: 192.168.171.18 is the ip of your server.

Comment: So you are telling me, I should connect to "192.168.171.18" because it is the IP of the device that is the server? And I should not be portforwarding anything?

Comment: What port should I be connecting to? I am not getting any further when trying to connect to that specific IP with port 1440.

Comment: Indeed the same port as where your server is listening on. But you have to remove the first .accept() from your bad server code. Otherwise your server cannot communicate with the first client.

Comment: I am now letting the client connect to the host using the .18 IP. Both are on port 1440. I removed the serverSocket.accept() method before the while loop. Both devices are on the same wifi network. The client is sadly still not connecting to the server. Could anything else be wrong?

Comment: Your client has a socket time out exception? Show your client code and switch off the firewall.

Comment: Okay, everything works! I have one last question, how would I let the devices connect to each other without knowing the IP of the other device? When I want to be able to support multiplayer in a game?

Comment: `how would I let the devices connect to each other`. That is wrongly formulated. A client app on one device would connect with a server app on another device.

Comment: How would I find out, when connected to a wifi network, what servers are open, like the one on the galaxy S6? - I have no idea how I would search for this question on google due to my limited english.

Comment: If the client 'sees' that it's ip is for instance 192.168.1.19 then the client should try to connect with all possibilities of 192.168.1.###. One will be the server. Just make a loop to try them all.

Comment: Ah good idea. Thanks for all your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client code use 192.168.171.18 which is the local ip of your server. Use the same port as where the server is listening on. So do not use a public ip.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely swallowing a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) in your catch block around creating the `ServerSocket`. You'd then be swallowing loads of NPEs in the second and third catch blocks where you accept connections. Not over-catching would have helped you here ;)

On a larger level, Android (by default) doesn't like it when you perform I/O on the application's main thread. Check out Android's guidelines on [Designing for Responsiveness](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

The best solution may be to create your own separate thread to handle this work. `AsyncTask` is a common and easy Android paradigm that you run across for performing work off the main thread, but it actually would *not* be very well-suited for this: It's designed for short background tasks, not long-running ones like socket listening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wouldn't the errors be showing in logcat if I had gotten them? I am seeing zero errors when starting the server. Also, I thought I am already starting the server on a different thread than the main one. What is the difference with what you are saying?

Comment: Interesting, I'll check again then. I ran your provided code and it worked once I did it off the main thread, so I had assumed incorrectly. Another thought - are you trying to open the connection via WiFi or cell network?

Comment: I am trying to open the connection via WiFI. Both android devices are connected to the same wifi; when starting the server on PC, I can connect one of the devices (via wifi) to the server. When I start the server on one of the devices, the other device can't connect (again same WiFi).

Comment: You are talking about wifi but not using the wifi ip.

Comment: @John, Something else I noticed - why are you `accept`'ing twice before starting a `CommunicationThread`? I can open a connection just fine to the Android server. Once I comment out the first `accept` and let just the one inside the loop handle it, the processing starts to actually occur.

Comment: Agree, if my comment above about double-accept was the problem, I'll make a different answer.

Comment: Yep, I failed. I think the problem is my bad understanding of Networking and IP Adresses. I wanted to say, the problem is probably in there.

Comment: Cool :) I added a second answer covering that, if you still want to accept an answer. I'm going to leave this one up as well since it is relevant to anyone who doesn't know about Network I/O and the Main Thread on Android.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're `accept`'ing one too many times. You call `accept`, which successfully answers the first incoming connection, and then you do nothing with that and start waiting for a second connection before you begin any processing.

This may have worked going from device -> PC due to some timing or lifecycle issues causing two connections to be opened; I'm not sure.

Comment: I will test this out again but I think it was not the problem. Thanks for the catch anyway though.

Comment: Good catch @tophyr. And John you should indeed as fast as you can remove the first accept().